# get file with glob and require

Tags: typescript, glob

hi i have two classes:

```
export class EmployeeController implements IController {
  public path = '/employee';
  public router = Router();

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository()
    private readonly employeeRepository: EmployeeRepository,
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }

  private initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.post(`${this.path}/add`, this.registration);
  }
  private registration = async (
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    next: NextFunction,
  ) => {
    const EmployeeDTO = request.body;
    console.log(EmployeeDTO);
  };
}
```

and:

```
export class DepartamentController implements IController {
  public path = '/departament';
  public router = Router();

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository()
    private readonly departamentRepository: DepartamentRepository,
  ) {
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }

  private initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.post(`${this.path}`, this.test);
  }

  private test() {
    return console.log('test');
  }
}
```

and I have the following function to get the files with the glob that seems to work:

```
let rootDir: string =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'src' : 'build/src';
let pattern: string = rootDir + '/modules/**/controllers/*.{js,ts}';
glob.sync(pattern).forEach(file => {
  this.controllers.push(require(resolve(file)));
});
this.controllers.forEach((item) => console.log(item.path))
```

with the glob I'm able to get the files:

```
[
  {DepartamentController: [class DepartamentController]},
  {EmployeeController: [class EmployeeController]}
]
```

but for some reason when I try to go through it to get the path or route variable I have undefinied as a value:

```
this.controllers.forEach((item) => console.log(item.path))
```

in the console.log above I get undefinied as value foreach my array

Comment: Try putting console log inside glob.sync function like below. Then see the file object info.
glob.sync(pattern).forEach(file => {
    this.controllers.push(require(resolve(file)));
    console.log(file);
});

Comment: src/modules/departament/controllers/index.ts
src/modules/employee/controllers/index.ts, this is only path to my files